# Order table based on specific column count

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have a `projects` table with the following columns  `id`, `project_name`, `remix_of`
A project can be a remix of another project and the id of the project being remixed is stored in the `remix_of` column

```
id | project_name | remix_of
----------------------------
1  | 1st Project  | 0
2  | 2nd Project  | 0
3  | 3rd Project  | 2
4  | 4th Project  | 1
5  | 5th Project  | 2
```

I want to query all the projects, ordering by the amount of times it has been remixed, in this case it would be:

```
2nd Project | 2 remixes  
1st Project | 1 remix  
3rd Project | 0  
4th Project | 0  
5th Project | 0
```

I'm using MySQL and have little experience with SQL overall.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, I want to order by the amount of times it has been remixed, for example 3rd and 4th project have both remixed the 2nd Project, so the 2nd Project has 2 remixes and it should appear first

Comment: You should accept, if that's what you want, @Strawberry. That was what I was writing before I saw his post. I believe that's the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `left join` or correlated subquery:

```
select p.project_name,
       (select count(*) from projects pr where pr.remix_of = p.id) as remixes
from projects p 
order by remixes desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,project_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,remix_of INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'1st Project',NULL),
(2,'2nd Project',NULL),
(3,'3rd Project',2),
(4,'4th Project',1),
(5,'5th Project',2);

SELECT x.project_name
     , COUNT(y.id) remixes 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.remix_of = x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.project_name;
+--------------+---------+
| project_name | remixes |
+--------------+---------+
| 1st Project  |       1 |
| 2nd Project  |       2 |
| 3rd Project  |       0 |
| 4th Project  |       0 |
| 5th Project  |       0 |
+--------------+---------+
```

Comment: your fingers are faster than mine :)

Comment: @Michel actually i find the speed at which I can type 'INT NOT NULL' slightly disturbing :-\

Answer (score 0):

To query based on number of remixes, you can group by remix_of and get the `COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT remix_of AS project_id, COUNT(*) AS numRemixes
FROM myTable
GROUP BY project_id;
```

Then, if you need to get the values from the original table, just do a `JOIN`. You may want a left join to get 0 values:

```
SELECT m.id, m.project_name, COALESCE(mt.numRemixes, 0) AS numRemixes
FROM myTable m
LEFT JOIN(
   SELECT remix_of AS project_id, COUNT(*) AS numRemixes
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY project_id) mt ON mt.project_id = m.id
ORDER BY numRemixes DESC;
```